# AWS CLI CloudTrail "lookup-events" filter accessKeyId

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I want to read events from the CloudTrail only with a specific accessKeyId.

I saw the command "aws cloudtrail lookup-events", but the attributes for filter are only: Event ID,Event name,Event source,Resource name,Resource type,User name

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=AccessKeyId,AttributeValue=${ACCESS_KEY_ID}

from here:
https://deeb.me/20190201/list-ips-from-cloudtrail-events

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to download the data using the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 sync s3://path/to/CloudTrail/data/2020/05/27 .
```

Then you can do multiple one-liner queries using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), for example:

```
zcat *.gz | jq '.Records[] | select(.userIdentity.accessKeyId == "ACCESS_KEY_ID")
```

Answer (score -1):

aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=AccessKeyId,AttributeValue=accessKeyId